# remove string from text file keep float

Tags: python, string, file

I'm looking to remove lines with strings or empty lines in a text file. It looks like this. As you can see the header repeat it self throught the file. The numbers of lines with data vary from each block. I need it to import as an array in numpy. At first I had comma for decimal point at least I was able to change that.

I tried this but it doesn't work at all:

```
from types import StringType

z = open('D:\Desktop\cycle 1-20 20-50 kPa (dot).dat', 'r')
for line in z.readlines():
    for x in z:
        if type(z.readline(x)) is StringType:
            print line


z.close()
```

Example of data:

```
bla bla

cyclical stuff                      Time:   81.095947   Sec 2012-08-02 17:05:42
stored :    1   cycle           stores for :    62  seg-cycle
Points :    4223
Servo_Hyd count Temps   Servo_Air pressure  Servo_Hyd load Servo_Hyd LVDT1  Servo_Hyd LVDT2 Servo_Hyd LVDT3
name1    name1    name1 name1   name1   name1   name1
1   60.102783   0.020013755 89.109558   0.3552089   0.4015148   -0.33822596
1   60.107666   0.020006953 89.025749   0.35519764  0.4015218   -0.33821729
1   60.112549   0.02000189  88.886292   0.3551946   0.4015184   -0.33822691
1   60.117432   0.020007374 89.559196   0.35519707  0.40151948  -0.33823174
1   60.122314   0.019991774 89.741402   0.35519552  0.40151322  -0.33822927
1   60.127197   0.020003742 89.748924   0.35520011  0.40150556  -0.33822462

bla bla

cyclical stuff                      Time:   81.095947   Sec 2012-08-02 17:05:42
stored :    1   cycle           stores for :    62  seg-cycle
Points :    4223
Servo_Hyd count Temps   Servo_Air pressure  Servo_Hyd load Servo_Hyd LVDT1  Servo_Hyd LVDT2 Servo_Hyd LVDT3
name1    name1    name1 name1   name1   name1   name1
1   60.102783   0.020013755 89.109558   0.3552089   0.4015148   -0.33822596
1   60.107666   0.020006953 89.025749   0.35519764  0.4015218   -0.33821729
1   60.112549   0.02000189  88.886292   0.3551946   0.4015184   -0.33822691
1   60.117432   0.020007374 89.559196   0.35519707  0.40151948  -0.33823174
1   60.122314   0.019991774 89.741402   0.35519552  0.40151322  -0.33822927
1   60.127197   0.020003742 89.748924   0.35520011  0.40150556  -0.33822462
```

Comment: `if line[0].isdigit(): whatever()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python will read all file elements as strings initially unless you cast them, so your method won't work.

Your best bet is probably to use a regular expression to filter out lines with non-data characters in them.

```
f = open("datafile")
for line in f:
  #Catch everything that has a non-number/space in it
  if re.search("[^-0-9.\s]",line): 
     continue
  # Catch empty lines
  if len(line.strip()) == 0:
     continue
  # Keep the rest
  print(line)

f.close()
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! All I had to do is to modify _if re.search("[^-0-9.\s]"):_ for _if re.search("[^-0-9.\s]",line):_ and rock on.

Comment: @Starter2 can you mark it as the answer if it answers your question? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using `numpy.loadtxt` ? it has a very nice interface exactly for these cases.
See the [documentation here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt)

```
yourArry = np.loadtxt(open('yourfilename.txt', skiprows=7)
```

Also, since you have the heder (which should be header as an something which can be found in the top of a file) you could split you file into multiple files. You could do it with Python, or you could use the UNIX command `csplit`. How to do it, and what you will get:

```
oz123@:~/tmp> csplit -k data.txt   '/^bla/' '{*}'
0
787
786
oz123@:~/tmp> ls xx
xx00  xx01  xx02
oz123@:~/tmp> ls xx00
xx00
oz123@:~/tmp> cat xx00
oz123@:~/tmp> cat xx01
bla bla

cyclical stuff                      Time:   81.095947   Sec 2012-08-02 17:05:42
stored :    1   cycle           stores for :    62  seg-cycle
Points :    4223
Servo_Hyd count Temps   Servo_Air pressure  Servo_Hyd load Servo_Hyd LVDT1  Servo_Hyd LVDT2 Servo_Hyd LVDT3
name1    name1    name1 name1   name1   name1   name1
1   60.102783   0.020013755 89.109558   0.3552089   0.4015148   -0.33822596
1   60.107666   0.020006953 89.025749   0.35519764  0.4015218   -0.33821729
1   60.112549   0.02000189  88.886292   0.3551946   0.4015184   -0.33822691
1   60.117432   0.020007374 89.559196   0.35519707  0.40151948  -0.33823174
1   60.122314   0.019991774 89.741402   0.35519552  0.40151322  -0.33822927
1   60.127197   0.020003742 89.748924   0.35520011  0.40150556  -0.33822462

oz123@:~/tmp> cat xx02
bla bla

cyclical stuff                      Time:   81.095947   Sec 2012-08-02 17:05:42
stored :    1   cycle           stores for :    62  seg-cycle
Points :    4223
Servo_Hyd count Temps   Servo_Air pressure  Servo_Hyd load Servo_Hyd LVDT1  Servo_Hyd LVDT2 Servo_Hyd LVDT3
name1    name1    name1 name1   name1   name1   name1
1   60.102783   0.020013755 89.109558   0.3552089   0.4015148   -0.33822596
1   60.107666   0.020006953 89.025749   0.35519764  0.4015218   -0.33821729
1   60.112549   0.02000189  88.886292   0.3551946   0.4015184   -0.33822691
1   60.117432   0.020007374 89.559196   0.35519707  0.40151948  -0.33823174
1   60.122314   0.019991774 89.741402   0.35519552  0.40151322  -0.33822927
1   60.127197   0.020003742 89.748924   0.35520011  0.40150556  -0.33822462
```

Comment: Could you give an example?  My reading of those docs doesn't show a way to handle headers scattered throughout the file.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, I guess it assumes a `header` is really on the top and not somewhere in the file.

Comment: @Oz123 Which unfortunately is not the situation in the OP's question

Comment: @Chris, the OP has probably got all the data file from some instrument. This instrument - and I am guess here - spits single files. For some reason, the OP has them stacked to one file. Which should not be a problem to splitting them to multiple files and than reading them...

Comment: @Oz123, the instrument automatically append the data of different cycle through the test. I didn't stack them. I'm making a GUI to analyse the data, so I don't want the user to import multiple files. It may take more time, but it will be easier for the user.

Comment: @Starter2, make it easy for your USER, and for you as a programmer. Create a /tmp/yourAppGui and read the directory from there. Or ... make a few more line in Python and split the file. It does not matter.